# Tensorflow Categorical Label Outputs from LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a TF model where I I have four "input" variables that are all categorical: `id, code1, code2, code3`, and I want to output a categorical label `label1`.

To handle the categorical nature of my data, I've used embeddings because the input dimension is quite high:

```
num_cats = 4 # number of categorical features
n_steps = 5 # number of timesteps in each sample
n_numerical_feats =  0# number of numerical features in each sample
cat_size = [7954,  3500, 3000, 2000] # number of categories in each categorical feature
cat_embd_dim = [7953, 350, 300, 200] # embedding dimension for each categorical feature

cat_inputs = []
for i in range(num_cats):
    cat_inputs.append(Input(shape=(n_steps,), name='cat' + str(i+1) + '_input'))

cat_embedded = []
for i in range(num_cats):
    embed = Embedding(cat_size[i], cat_embd_dim[i])(cat_inputs[i])
    cat_embedded.append(embed)

cat_merged = concatenate(cat_embedded)

lstm_out = LSTM(2867)(cat_merged)
model = Model( cat_inputs, lstm_out)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'] )

model.fit([ X_tr_cat1, X_tr_cat2, X_tr_cat3, X_tr_cat4], y_train, epochs=10)
```

In my code, `y_train` is just an array of the labels, so I need to somehow transform it into a numerical array - fitting it to y_train gives me an error where Python can't cast my string vector y_train to floats. (I'm guessing using either onehot encoding or representing y_train as an embedded vector itself?)

I've also tried using one-hot encoding:

```
y2 = y_train.reshape(39770,)

y3 = y2.reshape(-1,1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
cat = OneHotEncoder()
c = cat.fit_transform(y3).toarray()

model.fit([ X_tr_cat1, X_tr_cat2, X_tr_cat3, X_tr_cat4], c, epochs=10)
```

But this also gives me the same error: `Cast string to float is not supported`

How do I train my model, and view the label predictions my model makes (not the vector or onehot representation, but the actual string label?)

EDIT: I tried using LabelEncoding on my y variables, but now it looks like my X's are still object/string types since `X_tr_cat1` returns type `O`. I thought the embedding already took care of this?

Comment: you should integer encode your X

Comment: Would that mean to use Label Encoding on it as well?